# Populate ListPreference with installed applications

Tags: java, android, listpreference

I've been working on a application where i want to select one of there installed applications and then i just need to store it(The Application package) in the ListPreference, But cant seem to find a working solution, Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `PackageManager.getInstalledApplications` method to get a list of installed Applications.

And use:

1. `PackageManager.getApplicationLabel(ApplicationInfo)` to get the Labels for `ListPreference.setEntries`.
2. `ApplicationInfo.packageName` to get the package name for `ListPreference.setEntryValues`.

As shown here:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> appList = pm.getInstalledApplications(
        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

int count = appList.size();
String[] appLabels = new String[count];
String[] pkgNames = new String[count];

for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
    ApplicationInfo app = appList.get(i);
    appLabels[i] = pm.getApplicationLabel(app).toString();
    pkgNames[i] = app.packageName;
}

prefList.setEntries(appLabels);
prefList.setEntryValues(pkgNames);
```

Then you can retrieve package name for any item and use `PackageManager.getApplicationInfo` to get `ApplicationInfo` object of that package.